# How to check the value change between different rows in a dataframe and represent it in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Everyone.

I'm new to python and pandas, that I met a problem that I need to check whether a value of a certain columns changed over time(different rows). I totally have no idea that how to solve this problem.

I create a simple sample to illustrate it clearly:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":[2011,2012,2013,2014,2011,2014,2014,2014,2011,2012,2012,2015],"Product":['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],"Value1":[1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]},index=['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'])
df

        Year    Product Value1
A       2011       A    1
A       2012       A    1
A       2013       A    1
A       2014       A    0
B       2011       B    1
B       2014       B    1
B       2014       B    0
B       2014       B    1
C       2011       C    0
C       2012       C    1
C       2012       C    1
C       2015       C    1
```

I want to check the value change through the years depend on different products, here is the logic to check:

1. If the value1 is 0 for a product at first, just delete this row until value1 become 1. (e.g. Product C in 2011)
2. If the value1 for a product is 1, then set the result as 0.(e.g. Product A in 2011 etc.)
3. If the value1 change to 0 from 1 in a certain year then set the result as 1 and delete other rows of that product within same year (e.g. Product B in 2014)

So the final result should looks like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Year":[2011,2012,2013,2014,2011,2014,2012,2012,2015],"Product":['A','A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'],"Value1":[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1],'result':[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]},index=['A','A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'])
df2

    Year    Product Value1  result
A   2011       A       1    0
A   2012       A       1    0
A   2013       A       1    0
A   2014       A       0    1
B   2011       B       1    0
B   2014       B       0    1
C   2012       C       1    0
C   2012       C       1    0
C   2015       C       1    0
```

I tried to use `pd.apply` to solve this problem, but I have no idea how to get another row value and compare to give out a new value.

Can someone help me?

Comment: productA 2014 is 0 in 2014

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is quite involved,  so I have built it up in stages

1. temporary columns with *first* value and *count* of *product* per *year*
2. then your core logic with is using `apply()` and fact have *first*
3. build a filter condition that is logic you provided
4. finally filter to rows you want and cleanup *delete* temp column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":[2011,2012,2013,2014,2011,2014,2014,2014,2011,2012,2012,2015],"Product":['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],"Value1":[1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]},index=['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'])
df = df.assign(
        # need first value for logic
        first=df.groupby("Product")["Value1"].transform("first"),
        # need count for delete rows logic
        count=df.groupby(["Product","Year"])["Value1"].transform("count"),
        # core logic ...
        result=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: 0 if ((r["first"]==0) or (r["first"]==r["Value1"])) else 1, axis=1),
        # delete / drop rows logic
        delete=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: r["count"]>1 and r["result"]!=r["first"], axis=1)
).drop(["first","count"], axis=1) # drop temp columns used in logic

# filter and drop column used for filter
df = df[~df["delete"]].drop(["delete"], axis=1)

print(df.to_string())
```

**output**

```
   Year Product  Value1  result
A  2011       A       1       0
A  2012       A       1       0
A  2013       A       1       0
A  2014       A       0       1
B  2011       B       1       0
B  2014       B       0       1
C  2011       C       0       0
C  2012       C       1       0
C  2012       C       1       0
C  2015       C       1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['result'] = abs(df['Value1'].diff()).bfill().astype(int)
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.